# How to add objects to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

In post service, I am using below method to parse and update Database:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(<String>);
        UserLogin userLogin = mapper.convertValue(node.get("UserLogin"), UserLogin.class);
        UserSecurityDetails userSecurityDetails = mapper.convertValue(node.get("UserSecurityDetails"), UserSecurity
```

Now, In get service, I want to send the same data by retieving from DB and adding to JSON. Could anyone suggest what is the best way?

Sample JSON to be formed:

```
{

"UserLogin":
    {
        "user_login_id": "10011",
        "user_password": "password"
    },
"UserSecurityDetails":
    {
        "user_sequence_id": "1",
        "seq_question_id": "1",
        "seq_answer": "Test Answer"
    }
```

}

Comment: use writeValueAsString(); of ObjectMapper class and put both "UserLogin" and "UserSecurityDetails" in bean class, mapper.writeValueAsString(created bean class);

Comment: @UtteshKumar, Could you please elobarate more...Do I need to put both classes in single bean??? Now, I will have two bean objects which I need to insert

Comment: yes put both classes in single bean, its like DTO class for your get call and convert that bean to string mapper.writeValueAsString(created bean class);

Comment: Hi Uttesh, For now I have almost 10 bean classes, For example I have added only two in the example..Is there any alternative???

Comment: Is all beans will be returned in response? according to your response u have to construct the dto class. construct a dto class which will be having only which is required in response. what will improve the response time and performance.

Comment: i wrote sample application year ago which as spring security,jersey rest,angularjs take a look, which may help you https://github.com/uttesh/AngularJERSEYRESTSpringSecurityTemplate

Answer (score 1):

Create a Wrapper POJO having `UserLogin` and `UserSecurityDetails`. Jackson will automatically `deserialize` to your object.

> It will be good practice to expect required Object instead of creating objects from String.

Your Wrapper class will be like

```
public class SecurityDetailsWrapper {
     private UserLogin;
     private UserSecurityDetails;

     // costructor

     // getters and setters
}
```

in your `Controller`'s method you can expect `SecurityDetailsWrapper`.

like

```
public void someFunction(@RequestBody SecurityDetailsWrapper wrapper) {
  // business logic
}
```

Jackson will takes care of `Deserialization`.

Comment: Hi Dilip, Now How Could I return/add this wrapper object to response (for a webservice in above specified format..) ??  Any sample code will be of great help

Comment: @SpringUser Same as i mentioned for Request. method will be like `public @ResponseBody SecurityDetailsWrapper someMethod() { // blah }`

Comment: @SpringUser If you dont want to annonate your method  with`@ResponseBody` , you can annonate your `Controller` with `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: @SpringUser you can use ResponseEntity of spring, if u don't want to use "@ResponseBody."